# Unable to reach websites

Tags: internet-connection

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 on my Laptop and have the problem that since a few weeks I can't reach some Websites while others work fine.
I'm sure that the Problem must be somewhere in my System, because in the Windows (**same** Laptop) everything works.

When I'm trying to reach one of those Sites I get redirected to the o2-search which tells me that the site couldn't be found.
One of the sites which doesn't work is http://www.putpat.tv if this helps you.

Comment: Can you give a few more details. Did putpat.tv ever work in ubuntu. are you using firefox or chrome? thanks

Comment: OK, I use the Firefox and yes it worked before in Ubuntu (and still does if I boot a Ubuntu-Live-CD)

Comment: Did you try other web browsers already? Which DNS server is entered in your settings? You can try to enter another DNS, for example 8.8.8.8 (Google) in the network settings: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/net-editcon.html

Comment: changing the DNS-Server doesn't help, but using Chromium I can connext to the Sites.
But then there is still the question why it doesn't work with the Firefox.

Comment: please write here your hardware

Comment: its a Toshiba Satellite L650-1GT without any modifications
So a 2.4 GHz Dualcore CPU, 4GB Ram, ATI Radeon HD 5650 Graphicscard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem now by myself.

Just creating a new userprofile for the firefox and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

My best Guess if your Firefox is corrupt. the easiest way to test this is to try another browser. go to http://chrome.google.com and install chrome, or open your software center and get chromium. if you can access putpat.tv in either of those, your firefox is corrupt.

how to fix firefox:

in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge firefox firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support
```

this will uninstall FF, to reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support
```

Comment: Youre solution looks obvious but doesn't solve anything.

Comment: it reinstalls firefox?